# Combining mutual friends via SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
me = User.query.filter_by(username=me)

them = User.query.filter_by(username=them)

my_friends = me.friends.all()

their_friends = them.friends.all()
```

If `my_friends` returns `['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']`

and `their_friends` returns `['user1', 'user2', 'user3']`

How do I get the mutual friends between the two users?

I can use

```
list(set(my_friends).intersection(their_friends))
```

but I'd rather do it through SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`me = User.query.filter_by(username=me)`

`them = User.query.filter_by(username=them)`

`my_friends = me.friends`

`their_friends = them.friends`

`my_friends.intersect(their_friends)`

is what I needed.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be giving me issues when I switched from SQLite to MariaDB.